# How to insert a json object array to mongodb in golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

My json looks like the following,

```
[
  {
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": "val2"
  },
  {
    "key1": 2,
    "key2": "val2"
  }
]
```

This json comes in string format and I want the objects in the json array to be inserted as individual records in mongodb. I referred to https://labix.org/mgo but wasn't able to find enough examples on the above use-case. Appreciate your thoughts in finding a solution.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? You must have at least some code. However bad it may be - we were all beginners once.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Unmarshal](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Unmarshal) the JSON to []interface{} and [insert](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Insert) the result in the database. Assuming that `c` is an [mgo.Collection](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection) and `data` is a []byte containing the JSON value, use the following code:

```
var v []interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v); err != nil {
   // handle error
}
if err := c.Insert(v...); err != nil {
   // handle error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this example I will store the mixed array

test_string := `'[[1,"a","b",2,"000000",[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],"\"x","[y","'z",[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]]]'`

inside the mongodb as the json:

`{datum: [[1,"a","b",2,"000000",[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],"\"x","[y","'z",[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]]]}`

```
package main

import (
    "strings"
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
)



type datum2 struct {
    Datum interface{} `json:datum`
}





var userCollection = db().Database("goTest").Collection("users") // get collection "users" from db() which returns *mongo.Client

func typeinterface2mongo() {
    
    
    var datum2 datum2_instance
    var interfacevalue []interface{}
    
    test_string := `[[1,"a","b",2,"000000",[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],"\"x","[y","'z",[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]]]`
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(test_string), &interfacevalue); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    
    fmt.Println(test_string)
    fmt.Println(interfacevalue)
    datum2_instance.Datum=interfacevalue
    userCollection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), datum2_instance)
    fmt.Println(datum2_instance)
    fmt.Println(datum2_instance.Datum)  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have json data already please follow from step 2.

If you have Xml data first you need to convert to the json format by using this package("github.com/basgys/goxml2json")

```
 type JsonFileResponse struct {
    JsonData string        `bson:"JsonData " json:"JsonData"`
}

step 1: jsonData, err := xml2json.Convert(xml)
        if err != nil {
            panic("getting error while converting xml to json",err)
        }

step 2: session need to open by using your mongodb credentials.

    collection := session.DB("database name").C("Collection Name")
    err = collection.Insert(JsonFileResponse{JsonData :json.String()})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```