# How can I insert json string to MongoDB?

Tags: json, mongodb, go

I have a json string. Like this:

`"{"http_requests":[{"http_requests":{"code":"400","method":"PUT","value":89}},{"http_requests":{"code":"200","method":"PUT","value":45}}]}"`

I want to insert this json to mongodb. But I have error in my code.
The error is "cannot transform type string to a BSON Document: WriteString can only write while positioned on a Element or Value but is positioned on a TopLevel"

```
func insertJson(json_value string) {
   client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb+srv://abc:123@cluster0.wrzj3zo.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"))
   if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
   }
   ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
   err = client.Connect(ctx)
   if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
   }
   defer client.Disconnect(ctx)

   myDatabase := client.Database("my_db")
   myCollection := myDatabase.Collection("my_collection")
   myResult, err := myCollection.InsertOne(ctx, json_value)
   if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
   }
   fmt.Println(myResult.InsertedID)
}
```

How do I insert this json string to mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing's first: Add a ping to check if connection is succeeding after `defer client.Disconnect(ctx)`.

```golang
if err = client.Ping(ctx, readpref.Primary()); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("ping failed: %v", err)
}
```

If that doesn't throw an error, you can unmarshal your JSON string as explained in [stackoverflow: How to insert a json object array to mongodb in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448102/how-to-insert-a-json-object-array-to-mongodb-in-golang). However, in this case, use `interface{}` instead of slice as follows:

```golang
var v interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(json_value), &v); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Pass `v` to `InsertOne`.

> Note: This is one way of solving the problem. However, the recommended way to go about it is to unmarshal the JSON to go struct with json and bson tags, and pass the struct instance(s) to `InsertOne`.

Some references:

- [Go by Example: JSON](https://gobyexample.com/json)
- [How to Use Golang Structs With MongoDB](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-use-golang-structs-with-mongodb-f1772e4a1da3)
- [Use Struct Tags](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/usage-examples/struct-tagging/)

Answer (score 0):

> The insertOne() method has the following syntax:

```js
db.collection.insertOne(
   <document>,
   {
      writeConcern: <document> (optional)
   }
)
```

all you have to do is

```js
myCollection.insertOne(json_metrics)
```

Comment: when i just give json_string to input i get these errors: 
1. Not enough arguments in call to 'myCollection.InsertOne'
2. Cannot use 'json_value' (type string) as the type (context.Context, interface{}, *options.InsertOneOptions) or context.Context

Comment: try this `myCollection.insertOne(json_metrics)` (a lowercase i)

Comment: unfortunately the error persists: Unresolved reference 'insertOne'